# Error creando procedimiento MYSQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, stored-procedure, mysql-workbench, sintaxis, parametros

Tengo que crear un procedimiento muy simple que recibe dos parámetros (num1 y num2) de entrada y uno de salida (resultado).
El resultado es 1 si num1 es divisible por num2, y 0 si no.
Me da un error de sintaxis en la linea de crear procedimiento y lo tengo igual (con otros parametros obviamente) que en este link del manual de mysql
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html

Quizás haya algún error en el parámetro de salida cuando llamo a la función pero el error que me interesa resolver es el error de sintaxis en la declaracion del procedimiento(`Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1`
)

```
CREATE DATABASE ejerciciosCondicionales;
USE ejerciciosCondicionales;

DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS condicionales1;
CREATE PROCEDURE condicionales1(IN num1 int, IN num2 int, OUT resultado int)

BEGIN
    IF MOD(num1,num2)=0 
        THEN resultado=1;
    ELSE resultado=0;
    END IF;
END //

DELIMITER ;

call condicionales1(10,5,@resultado);
select resultado;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que el hecho de que no me funcionase la linea de crear el procedimiento, no dependía solo de esa linea si no del contenido del procedimiento también. Tras resolver algún error dentro del procedimiento (asignar valor a variables con set xD), ya me funciona.

```
use ejercicioscondicionales;
    DELIMITER //
    DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS ejercicio1;
    CREATE PROCEDURE ejercicio1 (in num1 int,in num2 INT,out resultado INT)
    BEGIN 
        IF MOD(num1,num2)=0 THEN set resultado=1;
        ELSE set resultado=0;
        END IF;
        SELECT resultado;
    END //
    DELIMITER ;
    call ejercicio1(10,5,@resultado);
    select @resultado as son_divisibles;
```